# Easiest way to impliment multithread in this function [Python]

Tags: python, multithreading

So I have data known as `id_list` that is coming into the function in this format `[(u'SGP-3630', 1202), (u'MTSCR-534', 1244)]`. The format being two values paired together, there could be 1 pair or a hundred pairs.

This is the function:

```
def ListParser(id_list):
    list_length = len(id_list)
    count = 0
    table = ""

    while count < list_length:
        jira = id_list[count][0]
        stash = id_list[count][1]
        count = count + 1
        table = table + RetrieveFromAPI(stash, jira)

    table = TableFormatter(table)
    table = TableColouriser(table)

    return table
```

What this function does is goes through the list and extracts the pairs and puts them through a function called `RetrieveFromAPI()` which fetches information from a URL.

Anyone have an idea on how to impliment multithreading here? I've had a shot at splitting both lists up into their own lists and getting the pool to iterate through each list but it hasn't quite worked.

```
def ListParser(id_list):
    pool = ThreadPool(4)
    list_length = len(id_list)
    count = 0
    table = ""
    jira_list = list()
    stash_list = list()

    while count < list_length:
        jira_list = jira_list.extend(id_list[count][0])
        print jira_list
        stash_list = stash_list.extend(id_list[count][1])
        print stash_list
        count = count + 1

    table = table + pool.map(RetrieveFromAPI, stash_list, jira_list)
    table = TableFormatter(table)
    table = TableColouriser(table)

    return table
```

The error I'm getting for this attempt is `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

EDIT 2: Okay so I've managed to get the first list with tuples split up into two different lists, but I'm unsure how to get multithreading working with it.

`jira,stash= map(list,zip(*id_list))`

Comment: What do you mean it hasn't worked? What happened?

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy just added the error to the main post then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working too hard! From `help(multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool)`

```
map(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None)
    Apply `func` to each element in `iterable`, collecting the results
    in a list that is returned.
```

The second argument is an iterable of the arguments you want to pass to the worker threads. You have a list of lists and you want the first two items from the inner list for each call. `id_list` is already iterable, so we're close. A small function (in this case implemented as a `lambda`) bridges the gap.

I worked up a full mock solution just to make sure it works, so here it goes. As an aside, you can benefit from a fairly large pool size since they spend much of their time waiting on I/O.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def RetrieveFromAPI(stash, jira):
    # boring mock of api
    return '{}-{}.'.format(stash, jira)

def TableFormatter(table):
    # mock
    return table

def TableColouriser(table):
    # mock
    return table

def ListParser(id_list):
    if id_list:
        pool = ThreadPool(min(12, len(id_list)))
        table = ''.join(pool.map(lambda item: RetrieveFromAPI(item[1], item[0]),
            id_list, chunksize=1))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
    else:
        table = ''
    table = TableFormatter(table)
    table = TableColouriser(table)
    return table

id_list = [[0,1,'foo'], [2,3,'bar'], [4,5, 'baz']]

print(ListParser(id_list))
```

Comment: This looks great, I just tried it and it looks like it's doing everything right but then I'm being hit with. `    ValueError: Number of processes must be at least 1`. Anything I should check/try to fix that?

Comment: Okay so just setting the ThreadPool() to 4 seems to fix it, but I guess thats not the most optimised version. Thanks for the help though, it works!!

Comment: The ValueError can happen if you pass in an empty `id_list`. I updated the code to check. I just pulled 12 out of a hat... nothing special about it except that my gut feeling is that you can drive more than 4 requests simultaneously. The real number (if it even matters!) would need some experimenting and tweaking.